# st_buffer() not preserving the shape of the original polygons

Tags: r, buffer, sf

I am currently trying to create buffers of 5km around polygons of the region of interest. However, every time I increase the radius from 500 metres to 5000 metres, the shape of the buffer is not similar to the shape of the original polygons. How do I preserve the shape as I scale up the radius of the buffer?

Code:

```
trial <- st_read("C:\\Users\\vr235\\Downloads\\issuewithbufferusingsfpackage\\TownVillCity1.shp")
trial <- st_transform(trial, 32644)
```

Select 3 polygons from your shapefile to try

```
sel <- c(1,5,14)
geom <- st_geometry(trial[sel,])
buf <- st_buffer(geom, dist = 5000)
plot(buf, border = 'red')
plot(geom, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

**EDIT** The question has been modified based on one of the comments.

Comment: What's wrong with that buffer? As a buffer radius increases you will lose the shape and detail of the buffered feature, and eventually the buffer will tend to a circle. Think about what a 500km buffer round a 1km square will look like. It won't look like a square.

Comment: to see this, create several buffers, e.g. at 500m intervals, and you'll see the shape 'morph' and become more 'blobby'. if you want a larger scaled-up copy (which preserves shape) please amend the question, as you probably want a scale operation instead

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman for your comment.

Comment: @StevenKay I have modified the question based on your suggestion.

Comment: This edit makes it a question of what you want to do, and what you think "buffer" means, because you *cant* preserve the shape *and* do a buffer. A buffer in GIS is the polygon union of the set of all points within the buffer distance of the source polygon. If instead what you want to do is *resize* polygons, keeping the *same* shape then that's resizing. Edit the Q again and remove all mentions of "buffer" if that's what you really want to do.